# Array that defines product information and generates the html for the product

Tags: php, beginner

Is there a more productive way to do this? Is my code up to standards or up to best practices?

```
   <?php

    /*
      FILE:       index.php
      AUTHOR:     Darcey Mckelvey
      PURPOSE:    View Products
    */

    // Define product information
    $products[0] = array(
      'name' => 'Sneakers',
      'price' => 24.99,
      'category' => 'Shoes',
      'description' => 'Black sneakers. Good for walking or athletic activity'
    );

    $products[1] = array(
      'name' => 'Armani Red Silk Shirt',
      'price' => 379.99,
      'category' => 'Shirts',
      'description' => 'Fancy Italian red silk shirt. Very spiffy, sure to attract the ladies'
    );

    echo "<h2 style='text-align:center;'>Welcome to DropShop!</h2>
          <h3>Our Products</h3>";


    // Loop to display all products
    foreach($products as $product) {
      echo "<p><span style='font-weight:bold;'>" . $product['name'] . "</span><br />" .
      "Price: $" . $product['price'] . "<br />" .
      "Category: " . $product['category'] . "<br />" .
      $product['description'] . "</p>";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if this is the real code and not a sample (like, data you're getting in `$products` is not fetched from the database), then there isn't much use of hard-coding a PHP array just to immediately use it to display HTML paragraphs - why not just write everything as HTML?

Other than that, you're implicitly creating an array (there's no `$products = array()` first). It's not an error, but it can be a little confusing. My immediate reaction was "where is `$product` coming from?". Also, you don't need to declare each element separately, you can do everything "at once" like this:

```
$products = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'Sneakers',
    'price' => 24.99,
    'category' => 'Shoes',
    'description' => 'Black sneakers. Good for walking or athletic activity'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Armani Red Silk Shirt',
    'price' => 379.99,
    'category' => 'Shirts',
    'description' => 'Fancy Italian red silk shirt. Very spiffy, sure to attract the ladies'
  )
);
```

Also, mixing PHP and HTML in single file isn't good practice, except when you're just echo-ing data in a "view". Other than that, logic should be separated.

Answer (score 0):

There is not very much going on in your code. It is basically just a template, so not very much room for improvement when it comes to the logic. It could be a bit better when it comes to style and readability though. Allow me to refactor the code to the way I would write it:

```
<?php
$products = [
    [
        'name'        => 'Sneakers',
        'price'       => 24.99,
        'category'    => 'Shoes',
        'description' => 'Black sneakers. Good for walking or athletic activity',
    ],
    [
        'name'        => 'Armani Red Silk Shirt',
        'price'       => 379.99,
        'category'    => 'Shirts',
        'description' => 'Fancy Italian red silk shirt. Very spiffy, sure to attract the ladies',
    ],
];
?>
<h2 style='text-align:center;'>Welcome to DropShop!</h2>
<h3>Our Products</h3>

<?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
    <p>
        <span style='font-weight:bold;'>
            <?= $product['name'] ?> 
        </span>
        <br/>
        Price: $<?= $product['price'] ?>
        <br/>
        Category: <?= $product['category'] ?>
        <br/>
        <?= $product['description'] ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I did:

- I declare all the products at once, and use the short `[]` array notation. I find it a lot cleaner (and it's less typing)
- Most of the code is in fact html, so in stead of staying in php mode, I closed the php and started writing ordinary html in stead of echoing a concatenated string. Imo this is a lot less prone to errors. You are bound to miss a `.` or use the wrong type of quote somewhere when you concatenate all those strings. Also it is a lot easier to read, and your IDE should be able to spot errors in your html a lot easier this way.
- Note that I use the short echo notation `<?= 'hello' ?>` in stead of the more verbose `<?php echo 'hello' ?>`. It is perfectly [safe to use](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) since php 5.4 and I find it cleaner.
- On the other hand I do use the more verbose `foreach() : ... endforeach;`. I find it tricky sometimes to keep track of the braces inside templates and this adds to the readability imo.

Allow me to comment on @OliverMaksimovic remark about going for straight html in stead of using an array. I do believe it is much better to use an array here. It makes the code a lot easier to maintain (what if you want to change the markup of a product, you would have to make that change multiple times). Also, if you ever decide to fetch those products from a database or something, you could basically keep your template as is, you would just have to change the $products declaration.

I could go on about how I would use Objects for those products in stead of arrays, and there remain a few things to be said about the markup you are using (it is not very semantic, it should probably be a `ul` of `article`s at the least), but I think I gave you enough food for thought now.

I hope it helps, and do feel free to ask if anything is unclear!